# best way to seal 5mm pipe?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure

I'm working on a personal hobby extending the reach of my pressure sprayer, I'm using 5mm pipe to connect it all together, the issue I'm running into is once I start pumping pressure up, the little connectors I have give way and let the water out,

I was thinking about using cable ties to hold the pipe on but I wanted to know if there was a better way to seal a 5mm pipe.

[image: the connector]

Comment: use pipe clamps

Comment: There are many types of pressure sprayers.  What type of pressure are you working with?

Comment: It's not clear if the ID or OD is 5mm, but if you can get a push-to-connect fitting that fits the pipes OD, I find those are easy to use and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Problem that elastic hose inflates under pressure and slips from such "herringbone". Any glue on such hose, i think, very likely will be teared off.

Consider using pneumatic fittings, better are with sleeve nut. Nutted are tolerant to hose diameter and type, and fast-connect require exact hose size.

Another solution could be addition of *spring action hose clamp*, matched to hose diameter. Cable ties or cheap worm-gear clamps can help, but they are unreliable in such applications.

Variation of previous solution could be putting tightly a piece of pipe or rigid hose on the end of hose after herringbone insertion into it. This pipe will clamp hose to herringbone and prevent its inflation and slipping.

Usually hoses for garden are black in order to prevent algae growth inside, but this is not a problem while water flow is large. Also some polymers degrade under sun radiation.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with compression fittings and use inner sleeves so the pipe is compressed onto the sleeve by the olive as it is a soft pipe.

[image]

Comment: good idea but needs a threaded union and nut combo for fittings,

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 that is what is meant by "compression fittings".

Comment: there are many types of compression fittings, I was just pointing out you need more than what is shown and that must match the hose material dimensions for OD and ID .

Answer (score 1):

Hose clamps are normally used on hose.

as above
[image]

Comment: good idea............if it increases the pressure rating

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 These just keep the tube from slipping off the barb. I doubt the pressure rating of either part takes that into account. It's generally assumed that you will use something like this with a barb fitting if it's got to withstand any significant pressure.

Comment: I don't disagree.  To prevent slipping the friction must be (much?) greater than the static force of water due to peak pressure * area.  A reliable compression fitting or adhesive is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Leak proof friction fittings with 60psi will be a challenge.  I have had some success and many failures using PU polyurethane hose and fittings for water irrigation on 4 mm ID hose.

PU adhesive is best, I think, also called sub-floor adhesive in large tubes. But todays low volatile types cure slow in a day with exposure to air but stronger better adhesion  than epoxy.

You might consider adhesive inside or out.

### added

If you absolutely must separate the pipes annually, then try to find air or fluid hose threaded compression fittings and don't over-tighten.

[image]

The retention seal & strain depends on the rise of hose pressure due to the sprinkler starting.

Comment: I was hoping to not resort to using Glue but considering you have experience with these things and I haven't, it might be best to try it. thanks for the advice!

Comment: Combine this compression fitting with the olive and insert I show and you are good to go. Personally used on many air systems and on my Volvo estate when I had air adjustable shocks on the rear.